# Leet Code: Find all starting indices of substring(s) in s that is a concatenation of each word

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Leet Code Question: You are given a string, s, and a list of words, words, that are all of the same length. Find all starting indices of substring(s) in s that is a concatenation of each word in words exactly once and without any intervening characters.

For example, given: s="barfoothefoobarman" & words=["foo", "bar"], return [0,9].

How to implement it with suffix tree or with better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my running solution with all 169 test cases passed:

```java
public class Solution {
    public List<Integer> findSubstring(String S, String[] words) 
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> toFind = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> found = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int wordsTotalLength = words.length, wordLength = words[0].length();


        //create a map to find the words 
        for (int i = 0; i < wordsTotalLength; i ++){
            if (!toFind.containsKey(words[i])){
                toFind.put(words[i], 1);
            }
            else{
                toFind.put(words[i], toFind.get(words[i]) + 1);
            }
        }



        for (int i = 0; i <= S.length() - (wordsTotalLength * wordLength); i ++){
            found.clear();
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < wordsTotalLength; j ++){
                int k = i + j * wordLength;
                String sub = S.substring(k, k + wordLength);

                //if we donot find any matching word in dictionary , just break;
                if (!toFind.containsKey(sub)) break;


                //or else if the word is in 'toFind' the dictionary 
                // then put it in the 'found' dictionary 

                if(!found.containsKey(sub)){
                    found.put(sub, 1);
                }
                else{
                    found.put(sub, found.get(sub) + 1);
                }


                if (found.get(sub) > toFind.get(sub)) break;
            }

            //if there is a continuous match 
            //put it in the result array
            if (j == wordsTotalLength) result.add(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```